# A MIT-licensed File shredder for Windows command line

Tags: windows

I want a file shredder for Windows which is:

- Licensed under MIT, or atleast free to Distribute
- Doesn't require installation.
- Can be used Command-line ( Therefore only a exe/bin file)

I want to distribute it within my software so I need it to be licensed to distribute freely.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Be aware that such a file shredder can only operate correctly [on hard drives](https://eraser.heidi.ie/do-solid-state-drives-ssds-really-destroy-data/), since more and more SSD drives are in use, this would not give a reliable protection.